# Android Studio: Spinner no muestra item seleccionado

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un `spinner` que al seleccionar uno de sus items se queda en blanco y no muestra el item seleccionado. El desplegar el `spinner` si me muestra la lista pero al seleccionar cualquier item se cierra la lista y el `spinner` se queda en blanco.

```
// LAYOUT PRINCIPAL CON EL SELECTOR SPINNER.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ActTienda">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTienda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Empresa"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
// LAYOUT PARA MOSTRAR EL ITEM SELECCIONADO.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCodigo"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EF5350"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
// LAYOUT PARA MOSTRAR EN LA LISTA DE ITEMS.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCodigo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
//  ADAPTADOR 

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.gestnet.R;
import com.example.gestnet.modelos.Empresa;
import java.util.List;

public class SpinnerAdaptadorEmpresa extends ArrayAdapter<Empresa> {
  private Context context;

  List<Empresa> datos = null;

  public SpinnerAdaptadorEmpresa(Context context, List<Empresa> datos)
  {
    super(context, R.layout.spinner_item_seleccionado, datos);
    this.context = context;
    this.datos = datos;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    if (convertView == null)
    {
      convertView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_seleccionado,null);
    }
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCodigo)).setText(datos.get(position).getCodigo());
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre)).setText(datos.get(position).getNombre());
    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null)
    {
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_lista, parent, false);
    }

    if (row.getTag() == null)
    {
      Holder holder = new Holder();
      holder.setCodigo((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCodigo));
      holder.setNombre((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre));
      row.setTag(holder);
    }

    Empresa empresa = datos.get(position);
    ((Holder) row.getTag()).getCodigo().setText(empresa.getCodigo());
    ((Holder) row.getTag()).getNombre().setText(empresa.getNombre());

    return row;
  }

  private static class Holder
  {
    private TextView codigo;
    private TextView nombre;

    public TextView  getCodigo()                {  return codigo;  }
    public void      setCodigo(TextView codigo) { this.codigo = codigo; }
    public TextView  getNombre()                { return nombre; }
    public void      setNombre(TextView nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }
  }
}
```

```
// CODIGO EN EL MAIN_ACTIVITY DONDE SE CREA EL SPINNER CON LOS DATOS DE UN ARRAY.
desplegableEmpresas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
desplegableEmpresas.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdaptadorEmpresa(this,listaEmpresas));
```

Comment: no veo problema en el codigo que subiste, podrias agregar el OnItemSelectedListener del spinner quizas este ahí el problema

Comment: No tengo aún el ```OnItemSelectedListener``` ya que todavía no quiero que haga nada cuando selecciono un item.  Hasta que no consiga que me muestre un item.

Cuando entra en la actividad el ```spinner``` debería mostrar el primer item que contenga, y eso no lo hace. Pero al desplegar y seleccionar un item tampoco me lo muestra en el ```spinner```.

Cuando consiga que eso funcione entonces añadiré el ```OnItemSelectedListener``` para que haga lo necesario según el elemento seleccionado.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: perdon pero no te estoy entendiendo. No creo que pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Quizás el error ocurre porque el fondo y las letras son del mismo color, ambos son blancos.

Comment: Yo tenia el mismo problema, me di cuenta que el array lo estaba llenado desde la nube, por lo tanto es asincrono y el resultado era null. Lo que hice fue asegurarme de cargar los valores y despues llenar el spinner